# "Guess The Number" In C But If Statements Don't Work Right

Tags: c, function, if-statement

I have a program in C that the user runs to play a "Guess The Number" game. It runs correctly to start but after the user enters 2 numbers (1 for the initial and 1 for the try again) the program repeats when it is supposed to have a limited number of tries.

Here is my code for the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    //----Guess a Number Game.-----------------------------------------
    // srand and rand needs the #include <stdlib.h> library

    srand(time(NULL)); //seeding the guess a number game with the system time, so the guess a # game always starts at a different point.
    int guess;
    int correctnum;
    correctnum = rand();

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%i",&guess);

    if(guess>correctnum)  // If aa is greater than bb AND aa is greater than cc.
    { 
      printf("Please enter another number, lower this time!");
      scanf("%i",&guess);
      main();
    }

    else if (guess<correctnum)
    {
      printf("Please enter another number, higher this time!");
      scanf("%i",&guess);
      main();
    }

    else if (guess==correctnum)
    {
      printf("You are a WINNER!\n");
      printf("You guessed the number right and it was %i!\n",correctnum);
    }
  int repeat;
  printf("Would you like to play again? 1=Yes and 2=No.");
  scanf("%i",&repeat);

  if(repeat==1)
  {
    main();
  }
  if(repeat==2)
  {
    printf("Hope you had a good time playing the game! See you soon!\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `main` recursively, use a ***loop***.

Comment: As for your question, you don't have a limit anywhere on how many "iterations" you should run.

Comment: You use `scanf()` before call `main()` and re-use it at the top of the function

Comment: Every time you call main again you reseed the rng.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't there some way that I can rewrite parts of my program so that a loop is not necessary, one where it uses only if statements?

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude said, use a loop for that, you don't need a recursive function

Comment: Calling `main` recursively is allowed in C. If you change language to C++ it's no longer allowed. It also "resets" your state, including reseeding the PRNG generator, and makes it harder to limit the number of iterations. As well as depletes the stack. It is also considered bad, even worse than using `goto` IMO.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This program is written in C not C++.

Comment: I know, but what you're doing is a bad habit, and bad habits tends to stick. What if you in the future want to program in C++? And try the same thing? Good habits tend to stick as well, so learning them early will benefit you for the rest of your programming life. Recursion instead of very simple loops (which will very easily allow you to limit the number of iterations) truly is a bad habit.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `main()` recursively. What you need is a simple loop. Something like:

```
int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int correctnum = rand();
    int guess;
    int done = 0;

    while (! done) {
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%i",&guess);

        if (guess>correctnum) { 
            printf("Please enter another number, lower this time!");
        } else if (guess<correctnum) {
            printf("Please enter another number, higher this time!");
        } else /* if (guess==correctnum) */ {
            printf("You are a WINNER!\n");
            printf("You guessed the number right and it was %i!\n",correctnum);

            done = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

You should probably check for errors from scanf() too, but first things first.

Comment: In your example, you use `scanf()` 2 times per loop

Comment: `main() { ... }` hasn't been valid C since 1999.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement all functions you want in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int guess;
    int correctnum;
    correctnum = rand() % 100;  #it's better to get a number between 1~100
    int done = 1;

    printf("guess the number:\t");
    scanf("%i", &guess);

    while(done){
        if(guess < correctnum){
            printf("Please enter another number, higher this time:\t");
            scanf("%i", &guess);    
        }

        else if(guess > correctnum){
            printf("Please enter another number, lower this time:\t");
            scanf("%i", &guess);
        }

        else if(guess == correctnum){
            printf("well done! if you want to play again, input 1, else input 0:\t");
            scanf("%i", &done);
            if(done == 1){
                correctnum = rand() % 100;
                printf("guess the number:\t");
                scanf("%i", &guess);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Hope you had a good time playing the game! See you soon!\n");
}
```